# Java: Buttons and Labes Layout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

What way would you suggest to layout (locate) Jbuttons and Jlabes in java in the fashion depicted in the picture below? Is there any tool for visually being able to place the components on a form in Java, rather than specifying the component locations in the code one by one.
Thanks

I am using **eclipse**

[image]

Comment: I think its homework ....Use GridLayout....

Comment: :)) no it is not! I just switched from C++ builder to java and have to port the codes from C++ to java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Swing GUI Builder](http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html) for visually layout component.

---

For Eclipse you can use [WindowBuilder](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/index.html). Look for **Installation** guide with update site of eclipse. Also take a look at the **Tutorial**.

Comment: Thanks, anything available for eclipse? something more updated than : http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jigloo-swtswing-gui-builder

Comment: You are welcome. We are happy to help you. I have edited my answer. If my answer is accepted by you, then mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org) comes with a visual UI builder for Swing.

Answer (score 1):

Use NetBeans, its have a create GUI tool!